# Want to create custom template in xcode 4.5

Tags: iphone, xcode, templates

It appears that Xcode 4.4 and 4.5 have changed their packaging.  Now it is one multi-gigabyte application.

I would like to add some customized templates to Xcode but none of the installation methos I have seen address the single module packaging of 4.5.

Can anyone shed some light on how to add a customized template to Xcode 4.5?

Thanks, in advance, for your help and guidance

Answer (score 5):

Put your custom project template to the folder 
~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates/

Next time you open xcode to create a new project and you'll find your project template